# Flutter gradient stops weird effect

Tags: flutter, gradient

I'm trying to add a transparent space on the `LinearGradient` Widget but I can't align the `stops` without creating this weird effect: [image: Flutter Stops Gradient]

On the right I have a smooth transition from the transparent to the red color, but on the left side the same doesn't happen, why is this happening, this is my code:

```
Container(
  width: media.size.width,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Color(0xFFf21d1d),
        Colors.transparent,
        Color(0xFFf21d1d),
      ],
      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
      end: Alignment.centerRight,
      stops: [0.4, 0.6, 1],
    ),
  ),
  child: EmptyWidget(),
)
```

The red color is just to make the effect more visible, I'd like to have that smooth transition on both sides, having only the middle visible with the transparent color.

Comment: `stops: [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]`

Comment: or more flexible: `stops: [0.5 - w, 0.5, 0.5 + w]` - where `w` is in `[0.0.. 0.5]` range